# Loop a color between set of icons

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change these icons to red one at a time but the trick is I want only one to be red at a time and switch back to white when the next one changes to red. I am drawing a blank on how to get this one. jQuery or vanilla is fine.

HTML (icons are white by default):

```
<div class="icon-row">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

EDIT:

Nothing triggering the color changes, I want it to keep repeating the process on an interval.

Comment: Would be helpful to give more info about what is triggering the color change. A click, timer, etc.

Comment: Like this -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/zr7k4257/

Comment: @adeneo correct, tysm

Comment: Not the downvoter, but you probably got it because this is not a coding problem, it is a "code this for me" request. The downvote description says "This question *does not show any research effort*; it is unclear or not useful"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a recursive function and a timer

```js
var els   = $('.icon-row .fa'), 
    delay = 500;

(function rec(el, time) {
    el.delay(time).queue(function() {
     var f = els.css('color','black').first();
     var n = $(this).css('color','red').next();
        
        rec(n.length ? n : f, time);
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
})(els.first(), delay);
```

```css
* {font-size: 30px; font-weight: bolder;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="icon-row">
  <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true">A</i>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true">A</i>
  <i class="fa fa-caret-right" aria-hidden="true">A</i>
</div>
```